# Data dependency detection bug with arm-none-eabi-gcc and -Ofast

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, cortex-m

I am writing a program for an Arm Cortex M7 based microcontroller, where I am facing an issue with (I guess) compiler optimization.
I compile using `arm-none-eabi-gcc` v10.2.1 with `-mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu11 -Ofast -mthumb`.

I extracted the relevant parts, they are as below. I copy some data from a global variable into a local one, and from there the data is written to a hardware
CRC engine to compute the CRC over the data. Before writing it to the engine, the byte order is to be reversed.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MEMORY_BARRIER asm volatile("" : : : "memory")
#define __REV(x) __builtin_bswap32(x) // Reverse byte order

// Dummy struct, similiar as it is used in our program
typedef struct {
    float n1, n2, n3, dn1, dn2, dn3;
} test_struct_t;

// CRC Engine Registers
typedef struct {
    volatile uint32_t DR; // CRC Data register Address offset: 0x00
} CRC_TypeDef;
#define CRC ((CRC_TypeDef*) (0x40000000UL))

// Write data to CRC engine
static inline void CRC_write(uint32_t* data, size_t size)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < (size / 4); index++) {
        CRC->DR = __REV(*(data + index));
    }
}

// Global variable holding some data, similiar as it is used in our program
volatile test_struct_t global_var = { 0 };

int main()
{
    test_struct_t local_tmp;
    MEMORY_BARRIER;
    // Copy the current data into a local variable
    local_tmp = global_var;
    // Now, write the data to the CRC engine to compute CRC over the data
    CRC_write((uint32_t*) &local_tmp, sizeof(local_tmp));
    MEMORY_BARRIER;
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles to:

```
main:
        push    {r4, r5, lr}
        sub     sp, sp, #28
        ldr     r4, .L4
        mov     ip, sp
        ldr     r3, [sp]              ; load first float into r3
        mov     lr, #1073741824       ; load address of CRC engine DR register into lr
        rev     r5, r3                ; reverse byte order of first float and store in r5
        ldmia   r4!, {r0, r1, r2, r3} ; load first 4 floats into r0-r3
        stmia   ip!, {r0, r1, r2, r3} ; copy first 4 floats into local variable
        ldm     r4, {r0, r1}          ; load float 5 and 6 into r0 and r1
        stm     ip, {r0, r1}          ; copy float 5 and 6 into local variable
        str     r5, [lr]              ; write reversed bytes from r5 to CRC engine
        ldr     r3, [sp, #4]
        rev     r3, r3
        str     r3, [lr]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #8]
        rev     r3, r3
        str     r3, [lr]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #12]
        rev     r3, r3
        str     r3, [lr]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #16]
        rev     r3, r3
        str     r3, [lr]
        ldr     r3, [sp, #20]
        rev     r3, r3
        str     r3, [lr]
        movs    r0, #0
        add     sp, sp, #28
        pop     {r4, r5, pc}
.L4:
        .word   .LANCHOR0
global_var:
```

The problem is now that the first float is loaded and its byte order is reversed (`rev r5, r3`) **before** the data has been copied from the global variable (happens with the `ldmia`/`sdmia`).
This is clearly not intended, leads to a wrong CRC, and I wonder why the compiler does not recognize this data dependency. Am I doing anything wrong or is there a bug in GCC?

Code in compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/ErWThc5dx

Comment: I may be being as dumb as a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), but your use of memory barriers  seems like no use at all to me. And what I think is a violation of strict aliasing with no memory barrier guard gives the compiler permission to do exactly what it is doing. What happens if you put a memory barrier where your complaint seems to indicate you want one?

Comment: I just introduced the barriers to mimic the behaviour as it is in our complete program (to avoid any optimization with the pushing and popping from main).
And yes, I am breaking stric aliasing there (is there a better way here? I guess not, as the data must be written in 4 byte blocks to the CRC engine), but IMO the dependency should be still recognized by the compiler. Or not?
Introducing a barrier after the copying of course helps, but normally it should not be necessary?

Comment: FWIW at this late date, either [removing the strict aliasing violation](https://godbolt.org/z/M4GocGEvK) or [inserting a compiler recognizable memory fence](https://godbolt.org/z/YfoedqoPs) seems to resolve this.